# adding a hotspot link on image in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have been stumbled on this for a while and after a few weeks of research I feel it safe to ask for help here.

What I am trying to do is this:  User clicks an image> Light box displays larger image > Larger image has a hotspot with a link to another page.

Is this possible? It seems simple enough but I can't seem to get it working.  Here is the code for reference.

```
<a href="images/createaccount_img.jpg" rel="lightbox" usemap="#Map" map name="Map" id="Map"><area shape="rect" coords="323,205,567,361" href="URL LINK 1" target="_blank" /><area shape="rect" coords="995,613,1191,668" href="URL LINK 2" target="_blank" > <img src="images/panel_login_11.jpg" width="152" height="27" alt="" />
```

SOLUTION:  the best option was to use http://fancybox.net/  which allows you to add many extra elements inside the box including: Divs, iframes, html and more! Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: map is a separate tag. So your code would never have worked.
This is how you normally use a map:

```
<a href="images/createaccount_img.jpg" rel="lightbox">
  <img src="images/panel_login_11.jpg" width="152" height="27" alt="" usemap="#map" />
</a>

<map name="map" id="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="323,205,567,361" href="URL LINK 1" target="_blank" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="995,613,1191,668" href="URL LINK 2" target="_blank" > 
</map>
```

That being said, I then figured to place a attribute `data-usemap` on the link that contains the url to the full-size image. Like this:

```
<a href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/examples/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" data-usemap="#map"><img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/examples/thumb-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Then I modified `lightbox.js` to read this attribute `usemap: $link.attr('data-usemap')` and set that attribute `$image.attr('usemap', _this.album[imageNumber].usemap);`

*Now the full-size image has the correct usemap set*.
But it **still does not** work!! I think this is because of div's that overlay on this image.
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKM7r/) I've worked on. Search for `//xxx added` to find the 2 lines I added. Maybe someone else could work on it some more.

In other words, I don't think it will be easy to create a mod over an unmodified lightbox.js.

A also want to note that a lot of scripts like lightbox also resize the full-size image to fit the screen (lightbox does not do this as far as I could see): THEN you would also need javascript to re-calculate the coordinates in the map(s) I guess.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you put into this! thank you so much.  It seems like it is so close to working... I will try to play with it some more.  If anyone can solve the the issue of it still not showing the hotspot let me know ! thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. I am curious however how you made nz_karl's answer work (that you accepted), since your question was clear: 'is it possible to have a hotspot inside lightbox, and if so, how to do it'. So how did you get the div to show up in lightbox? I've spent 2 hours on your question, at least inform me and future readers how you got nz_karl's answer to work in lightbox. Post some code or a fiddle. Otherwise this question is kind useless to future readers. Thank you!

Comment: I got it working by using http://fancybox.net/  Lightbox 1 and 2 are not set up to work with anything but images.  Fancybox allows many extra elements including: Divs, iframes, html and more.  I appreciate your help so much though.  I learned a lot about the order of code.  Again, thank you and all the best!

Comment: Thanks for the post-back, working solution and accept! See you around!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple HTML page that has a picture of a penguin with a hotpsot on the penguins head which links to www.google.com

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="hotspot_image" style=""><img alt="Image with Hot Spot that links to www.google.com" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Pygoscelis_papua.jpg/250px-Pygoscelis_papua.jpg" />
        <a href="https://www.google.com" style="position:absolute; width: 60px; height: 60px; left:100px; top: 40px; z-index:1; " ></a></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Now you just need to make the `<div>` containing the image and link show in your lightbox.

Hope this helps!